# jquery flip switch not working using jquery-toggles

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have created a simple example of using Simon Tabor's "jquery-toggles" plugin (https://github.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles).  And although it works, the graphics never show up.  I confirmed the CSS and JS is loading fine, yet still no images.  Can someone figure out why?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/jquery-toggles-master/themes/toggles-light.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/include/jquery-toggles-master/toggles.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toggle').toggles();
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="toggle toggle-select" data-type="select"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS & JS file too, or create a jsfiddle we can see? (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I tried to make a jsfiddle but couldn't do it...sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap your toggle with the proper theme.

```
<div class="toggle-light">
  <div class="toggle toggle-select" data-type="select"></div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/okupof/2/edit

If you view the source of http://simontabor.com/labs/toggles/ then you'll see more examples in `<div class="themes">`

Comment: Bad documentation....you are correct thanks.  In case anyone else wants to try the app, the documentation is wrong in regards to reading state / callback on change parameters.  Go through the code to reverse engineer...